# Why PCA needs to consider **perpendicular** distance and cater for maximal variance?

Tags: pca, least-squares

The question is

1. Why PCA needs to consider **perpendicular** distance?
2. Why PCA needs to cater for maximal variance?

For Question (1), from this [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/principal-component-analysis-pca-vs-ordinary-least-squares-ols-a-visual-explanation/):

It shows that OLS is to minimize the distance from the model and the dependent,e.g.,
[image]

while PCA is to minimize the **perpendicular** distance from the model and the PCA model line,e.g.,

[image]

Why PCA needs to consider **perpendicular** distance?

For Question (2), from this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/140579/51955), it mentions that the objective of PCA wants to achieve two objectives:

1. The minimum error
2. The maximum variance

My second question is **why we need maximum variance**? Does this objective have anything to do with the previous question on **perpendicular** distance?

Comment: `why we need maximum variance` Just we put it is the goal. Why needs to consider perpendicular distance? It is that same goal (hint keywords: rotation; pythagorean theorem).

Answer (score 4):

One way of stating the goal of PCA is to find the linear projection $W$ that gives you the "best" representation of your data for a given dimensionality. It defines "best" by the representation with the minimal squared reconstruction error.

When looking at PCA from 2 dimensions to 1 dimension, as you do there, you are not actually trying to find the line that best predicts $y$ from $x$. Rather, you're trying to find the combination of $y$ and $x$ such that the new, combined value "best" represents all your initial 2-D points.

Essentially, the reason PCA considers the perpendicular distance is because it doesn't actually try to model $y$ as a function of $x$.